# OpenLayers, Bing and a KML

Tags: javascript, kml, bing-maps, openlayers, proj4js

I'm trying to lay an KML over VirtualEarth Map in OpenLayers, but it doesn-t work. I guess it has to be something with the projection.

```
Map:
var options = {
    controls: [ new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
                ],
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds( -200000, -200000, 200000, 200000),
    numZoomLevels: 19,
    units: 'm',
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
 displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
sphericalMercator: true

};


map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);

var binghybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Hybrid", {
            type: VEMapStyle.Hybrid
});


KML:
var animals = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Animals", {
           projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "kml/animals.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });
```

Anybody?! Thank you.

Comment: Are you adding the "animals" layer to your map?
map.addLayers([binghybrid, animals])

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this document:
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html

**Edit** Example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/spherical-mercator.html

The key is in:

```
    var in_options = {
      'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
      'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    };
    var kmlOptionsIn = OpenLayers.Util.extend({ extractStyles: false },in_options);

    var features = new OpenLayers.Format.KML(kmlOptionsIn).read(kml);
```

Here the complete source to the example. (just copy/paste into an html file, load and click the "Add KML" button).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/OpenLayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src='http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1'></script>
    <script src="js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lon = 5;
        var lat = 40;
        var zoom = 5;
        var map, layer, vectors, formats;
        function init() {

            var options = {
                units: "m",
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
                restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
            };


            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);


            var hybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Bing Base Map",
            {
                sphericalMercator: true,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)

            });


            var venctor_options = {
                units: "m",
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
                restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
            };

            vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", venctor_options);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            map.addLayers([hybrid, vectors]);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
//            var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-30, 12);
//            map.setCenter(center, 1);



        }


        function deserialize() {

            var kml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'><Document><name>Granules</name><description>Exported on Wed Nov 24 2010 09:41:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)</description><Placemark><name>GRAN-46</name><description>{ ID:46, TYPE:'OPT', START_DATE:'7/23/2003 4:21:17 PM', END_DATE:'7/23/2003 4:22:13 PM', INGESTDATE:'3/25/2004 12:00:00 AM', EXTERNAL_ID:null, PIXELS:6000, LINES:37494, DATA_PRODIVER_ID:1, COMMENTS:'null' }</description><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing id=''><coordinates>-81.2162649929523,31.1248919963837 -81.177305996418,31.2556949853897 -81.0197220146656,31.781594991684 -80.8606449961662,32.3073099851608 -80.7000299990177,32.8328340053558 -80.5378299951553,33.3581640124321 -80.3739939928055,33.8832920193672 -80.2084729969502,34.4082159996033 -80.8601450026035,34.515996992588 -81.0217449963093,33.9903180003166 -81.18175598979,33.4644510149956 -81.3402259945869,32.9384009838104 -81.4972029924393,32.412172973156 -81.6527320146561,31.8857709765434 -81.8068569898605,31.359197974205 -81.8449699878693,31.2282310128212 -81.2162649929523,31.1248919963837 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>"

            var type = "kml";
            var in_options = {
              'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
              'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            };
            var kmlOptionsIn = OpenLayers.Util.extend({ extractStyles: false },in_options);

            var features = new OpenLayers.Format.KML(kmlOptionsIn).read(kml);
            var bounds;

            if (features) {
                if (features.constructor != Array) {
                    features = [features];
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < features.length; ++i) {
                    if (!bounds) {
                        bounds = features[i].geometry.getBounds();
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(features[i].geometry.getBounds());
                    }
                }
                vectors.addFeatures(features);
                map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

            }
        }

    </script> 
    <style type="text/css">
/**
 * CSS Reset
 * From Blueprint reset.css
 * http://blueprintcss.googlecode.com
 */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-weight:inherit;font-style:inherit;font-size:100%;font-family:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}
body {line-height:1.5;}
table {border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0;}
caption, th, td {text-align:left;font-weight:normal;}
table, td, th {vertical-align:middle;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content:"";}
blockquote, q {quotes:"" "";}
a img {border:none;}

/**
 * Basic Typography
 */
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #222;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 1em 1.5em;
}
pre, code {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    white-space: pre;
}
pre, code {
    font: 1em 'andale mono', 'lucida console', monospace;
    line-height:1.5;
}
a[href] {
    color: #436976;
    background-color: transparent;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #003a6b;
    background-color: transparent;
    font: 100% 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 130%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fcb100;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Map Examples Specific
 */
.smallmap {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tags {
    display: none;
}

#docs p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}    
    </style>
  </head> 
  <body onload="init()"> 
      <h1 id="title">KML Layer Example</h1> 

      <div id="tags"> 
        KML
      </div> 

      <p id="shortdesc"> 
          Demonstrates loading and displaying a KML file on top of a basemap. <button onclick="deserialize()">Add KML</button>
    </p> 

    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div> 

    <div id="docs"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The KML and Bing Maps should be working with the same projection and coordinate system. Have you tried setting them to be the same? This is in addition to Thqr's recommendation about addLayers (as you have a code snippet it is unclear if you are doing this or not)

In the general case, OpenLayers can reproject vector data but you will also need to include the Proj4JS library.

Answer (score 0):

Please bother that I use OpenLayers example by previous programmer. But, I made some innovative changes that even better. For now, I strongly recommend you to use Google Maps. Here I simplify a JavaScript where you can put in head tag:

```
    <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAl9RMqSzhPUXAfeBCXOussRTQDbvAygy0cfGJr8dEMAYKf3RWNBQqP9mjKIsqTfmAlz5LOJ3Xpy5s4w'></script>
```

Then, you may insert Google Maps into the OpenLayers as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lon = 5;
    var lat = 40;
    var zoom = 5;
    var map, layer, vectors, formats;
    function init() {var options = {
            units: "m",
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
        };
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Streets", 
        {
            numZoomLevels: 20,
            sphericalMercator: true,
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
        });
var vector_options = {
            units: "m",
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
        };
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", vector_options);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addLayers([gmap, vectors]);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
</script>
```

I'm just happy to help. Good luck!